# Displaying Polygon or Circles using KML with its Name on Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, kml

I can able to display KML on Google Earth.
Now I want to display the same on the Map..
How is this possible ?
Here is my KML attached...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
  <Document>
    <name>Hide and show labels</name>
    <Style id="sn_hide">
      <IconStyle>
        <scale>0</scale>
      </IconStyle>
    </Style>

    <StyleMap id="msn_hide">
      <Pair>
        <key>normal</key>
        <styleUrl>#sn_hide</styleUrl>
      </Pair>      
    </StyleMap>
    <Placemark>
      <name>Placemark 1</name>
      <description>Label hidding</description>
      <styleUrl>#sn_hide</styleUrl>
      <Point>
        <coordinates>-119.232195,36.016021</coordinates>
      </Point>
    </Placemark>
    <Placemark>
      <name>Placemark 2</name>
      <description>Label hidding</description>
      <styleUrl>#sn_hide</styleUrl>
      <Point>
        <coordinates>-119.232195,36.0162</coordinates>
      </Point>
    </Placemark>

  </Document>
</kml>
```

Thanks in advance ..
    ​

Comment: What map do you want to display it on? [Google Maps}(http://maps.google.com)?  Or a Google Maps API v3 map? For either your KML will have to be on a publicly available webs erver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display KML on a Google Map, it needs to be on a publicly accessible web server.

Then either use the Google Maps API v3 [KmlLayer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#KmlLayer) or [Google Maps](http://maps.google.com)

[Google Maps API v3 KmlLayer example from the documentation](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-kml)

Code to display the KML file:

```
    var chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(41.875696,-87.624207);
    var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 11,
      center: chicago,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);

    var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer('http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ggeoxml/cta.kml');
    ctaLayer.setMap(map);
```

[Here](https://maps.google.com/maps?q=http%3a%2F%2Fgmaps-samples.googlecode.com%2Fsvn%2Ftrunk%2Fggeoxml%2Fcta.kml&hl=en&sll=32.824552,-117.108978&sspn=0.691256,0.883026&t=h&z=10) is the same KML file displayed on Google Maps.

UPDATE:

http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/Point_Placemarks.Descriptive_HTML_kml.xml">Here is a local copy of the file from your comment displayed using the Google Maps API v3 geoxml3 third party parser
(KmlLayer seems to think it is an invalid document)

[Here is that KML displayed on Google Maps](https://maps.google.com/maps?q=http%3a%2F%2Fwww.geocodezip.com%2Fgeoxml3_test%2FPoint_Placemarks.Descriptive_HTML_kml.xml&hl=en&sll=32.824552,-117.108978&sspn=0.691256,0.883026&t=h&z=19)

Comment: http://kml-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/interactive/index.html#./Point_Placemarks/Point_Placemarks.Descriptive_HTML.kml
In this link, paste the KML code that i have said above.. Here after placing the code the Google earth shows the point names , but the same couldn't be able to display on a google map using api v3.